# SQL statement error

Tags: sql, oracle

Print the names of employees who are certified only on aircrafts with cruising range longer than 1000 KMs.

```
SELECT E.ename
FROM Employees E, Certified C, Aircraft A
WHERE C.aid = A.aid AND E.eid = C.eid
GROUP BY E.eid, E.ename
HAVING EVERY (A.cruisingrange > 1000)
```

Oracle's lack of support for the `HAVING EVERY` clause produces the error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of every, select the smallest one, and check that its bigger than 1000

```
SELECT E.ename
FROM Employees E
INNER JOIN Certified C ON  E.eid = C.eid
INNER JOIN Aircraft A ON C.aid = A.aid
GROUP BY E.ename
HAVING MIN(A.cruisingrange) > 1000
```

As Gordon said, I forgot to mention, I fixed your join syntax from implicit(comma separated) to **explicit** join syntax. Try to avoid the use of implicit join syntax in general that can lead to mistakes when dealing with more then two tables.

Comment: Yea, I didn't know what to use because he said 'less than 1000' but wrote an sql more then 1000.. @JoachimIsaksson , went with what he said:)

Comment: Plus you fixed the `join` syntax!

Comment: @morris No problem:)

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match the query - `select the maximum one, and check that its smaller than 1000` would indicate `having MAX(cruisingrange) < 1000` (presumably because you edited the query, but didn't update the explanation)?

Comment: One small item: Two employees with the same name meeting this criteria would get GROUP'd down to an apparently single record result.